# SAS less than or equal to sign

Tags: sas, conditional-statements

In some SAS code written by a former team member in our company he makes use of the symbol `-<` As far as I can work out, it means LE (<=) and so includes the RHS value of `a -< b` but not the LHS.  Can anybody confirm this?  Also, is it valid in other languages?

I tend to steer away from the symbol versions of conditional statements in SAS where I can, but was just wondering...I may have to translate similar code at some point soon.

```
proc format;
  value score
    low -< 100 = 'Low'
    200 -< 300 = '200 -< 300'
    300 -< 400 = '300 -< 400'
    400 -< high = 'High'
  ; 
run;
```

Comment: Can you provide more context?  `-<` is not a valid comparison operator, but it is valid syntax as part of a format definition.

Comment: An example would be:

    `proc format;
        value score
        low -< 100  = 'Low'
        200 -< 300 = '200 -< 300'
        300 -< 400 = '300 -< 400'
        400 -< high = 'High';
    run;`

Comment: Apologies for formatting - can't seem to get it to block :/

Comment: I think I understand what you mean about the format syntax, but could you please clear up which side of the inequality is included in the format label?  

Many thanks!

Comment: You could find out in 2 minutes using the SAS online documentation.
It reads as "low to less than 400" 200 to less than 300" etc.

Comment: I did have a good search but came up with nothing - probably because I wasn't aware that these are operators confined to PROC FORMAT.

Answer (score 3):

That is not a comparison operator.  It is part of the syntax of specifying a range of values in a format definition.  Here is the relevant description from the documentation.

> You can use the less than (<) symbol to exclude values from ranges. If you are excluding the first value in a range, then put the < after the value. If you are excluding the last value in a range, then put the < before the value. For example, the following range does not include 0:

```
0<-100
```

> Likewise, the following range does not include 100:

```
0-<100
```

> If a value at the high end of one range also appears at the low end of another range, and you do not use the < noninclusion notation, then PROC FORMAT assigns the value to the first range. For example, in the following ranges, the value AJ is part of the first range:

```
'AA'-'AJ'=1 'AJ'-'AZ'=2
```

You could read `a -< b` as meaning "from a to less than b". Similarly `a <- b` could be read as "from greater than a to b".